# Javascript, how to better deal with multiple filter options that lead to long branching if/else chains

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm using javascript to search through a google spreadsheet for items. I have several available filters, the issue is that for each filter I add in, I seem to have exponentially more if/else statements.

Let's say I can filter by name, type, and date. Date is required, but the other two options are not. I end up having to have an if/else for each unique combination to make sure I'm matching the correct inputs. If I want to add more ways to filter data it will get even messier.

Example:

```
  var filterReportType = !CheckIfBlank(reportType);
  var filterName = !CheckIfBlank(name);

  for(var i = 2; i < dataRange.length; i++)
  {
    if(dataRange[i][0] != "")
    {
      searchData.entriesSearched ++;
      if(CompareEntryDates(new Date(startDate), new Date(endDate), new Date(dataRange[i][0])))
      {
        if(filterName && filterReportType)
        {
          if(name == dataRange[i][2] && reportType == dataRange[i][3])
          {
            var newEntry = FillEntryObject(i, dataRange);
            entries.push(newEntry);
            searchData.entriesFound ++;
          }
        }
        else if(filterName)
        {
          if(name == dataRange[i][2])
          {
            var newEntry = FillEntryObject(i, dataRange);
            entries.push(newEntry);
            searchData.entriesFound ++;
          }
        }
        else if(filterReportType)
        {
          if(reportType == dataRange[i][3])
          {
            var newEntry = FillEntryObject(i, dataRange);
            entries.push(newEntry);
            searchData.entriesFound ++;
          }
        }
        else
        {
          var newEntry = FillEntryObject(i, dataRange);
          entries.push(newEntry);
          searchData.entriesFound ++;
        }
      }     
    }
  }
```

This is not a maintainable pattern, if I need to add more possible inputs to filter by then this chain of statements will become massive.

Edit: Why this is not a duplicate: I checked out that other question, and I see how it will shorten a very long statement, but I do not see how it will shorten a long chain of separate statements. I would still need to check for different combinations and I believe I would end up wit the same number of if/else statements anyways.

Comment: Checked that out, I'm not seeing how it applies as a duplicate. I do not see how that will make my chain any shorter. It could make a single long statement easier to manage, but I'm not sure about a lot of separate statements? I would just end up with many different arrays for different combinations of inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two suggestions:

1. Use successive filtering
2. Use the functional approach

For your code above this would mean:

```
var filterReportType = !CheckIfBlank(reportType);
var filterName = !CheckIfBlank(name);

if (filterName) {
   dataRange = dataRange.filter(function (elm) {
          return elm[i][2] === name; });
}

if (filterReportType) {
   dataRange = dataRange.filter(function (elm) {
          return elm[i][3] === reportType; });
}

// Check the index here: is it really starting from
// the third row? If so, you may need to adapt the
// filter methods above.
for(var i = 2; i < dataRange.length; i++)
{
    var newEntry = FillEntryObject(i, dataRange);
    entries.push(newEntry);
    searchData.entriesFound ++;
}
```

If you redesign your data model and the `FillEntryObject` function, you can narrow it even further down:

```
filters = { "name": name, "recordType": recordType }

for (var key in filters) {
    if (!CheckIfBlank(filter[key])) {
        dataRange = dataRange.filter(function (elm) {
            return elm[key] === filters[key]; });
    }
}

var entries = dataRange.map(MakeEntryObject);
```

For this to work, `dataRange` should use the name of the field as the second index (if that is not an option, you could map the names to the numbers) and `MakeEntryObject` should be a factory method for contructing entry objekts from dataRange rows.